# How does one pass string contains '\' from from asp.net server side to Javascript function?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How does one pass string contains '\' from from asp.net
server side to javascript function?

After checking parameters at client side, all '\' replaced with '' even,
replacing '\' with '%5C' at server side doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for that.

`parameter.Replace("\\", "\\\\")` solve it.

Answer (score 2):

`\` is a special character - basically it "escapes" the character after it. Try passing `\\` instead. BTW - if you're using C# you can use the @ character before a string to avoid needing to pass it as a double slash, e.g.

```
string path = @"c:\documents\mydocuments";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET to write a JavaScript string literal? ie. something like:

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("foo",
   "<script type='text/javascript'>"+
   "    var bar= '"+myBarValue+"';"+
   "</script>"
);
```

If so, then you are embedding text inside a delimited JavaScript string literal and you must use an escaping scheme that follows the syntax for string literals. In particular any `\` character inside the text must be escaped with `\\`, and any `'` character must be replaced by `\'`, since that's the delimiter being used in this case (JavaScript can use either type of quote to delimit strings).

What's more if you're using an inline `<script>` block like in the above example, you're actually embedding text in a string literal in an HTML element, so you have to do some HTML escapes too. In particular you have to break up any `</` sequences in the text, because that would end the script block. Also, in XHTML, there are no CDATA elements, so you'd also have to ampersand-escape any `<` or `&` characters in the text, except that would make it incompatible with legacy-HTML parsers. So to solve all these problems it is better to use JavaScript string literal escapes for that too, replacing `<` with `\x3C` and `&` with `\x26`.

Ideally what you would do would be to pass the simple string to a JSON encoder library, which would take care of escaping it appropriately for JavaScript. However I don't know of one for .NET that will escape the HTML for you as above, so you'd still need some replaces.